# How to write multiple conditional formula (39 conditions) for 7 columns in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, multiple-values, conditional, syntax

first, I must thank you all for the tips for new people who want to learn more on SharePoint to optimize their business.
I'm trying to find a solution to write expanded conditional formula according to 7 columns which are making 39 different situations in our business.
I tried some solutions without any success and I almost blew my head :-)
the problem is that as far as I know, only 19 IF can be used simultaneously, but I need 39!.
I would appreciate it if you have any workable solution

here is the sample which I'm trying to make:

=IF(AND(ISBLANK([COLUMN1]), ISBLANK([COLUMN2]), ISBLANK([COLUMN3]), ISBLANK([COLUMN4]), ISBLANK([COLUMN5]), ISBLANK([COLUMN6]), ISBLANK([COLUMN7])), “Result A” , “Result B”)
Using the above sample in 39 condition:

=
IF(-Condition1-),
IF(-Condition2-),
IF(-Condition3-),
.
.
.
IF(-Condition39-),

“-Result 1-”,
“-Result 2-”),
“-Result 3-”),
.
.
.
“-Result 39-”)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than 19 conditions then return an empty string on the last if statement of your first 19 condition group and then concatenate (Using the & operator) and add another 19 IF statement.

[image]

Took Reference from

[https://www.risual.com/2020/05/sharepoint-online-using-multiple-if-statements/#:~:text=Beware%20there%20is%20a%20limit,IF%20statements%20and%20so%20on](https://www.risual.com/2020/05/sharepoint-online-using-multiple-if-statements/#:%7E:text=Beware%20there%20is%20a%20limit,IF%20statements%20and%20so%20on).

Hope it will help to you