# SharePoint List - How to determine percentage complete based on completed columns?

Tags: list, calculated-column

I have 30 columns, most of them using Yes/No, but also some text. Is there a way to have a Progress column that will automatically calculate how many of the columns have been completed and determine the percentage completed?

So, if 15 columns have been completed by selecting Yes/No, then the percentage complete column will show 50%.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Lucy

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach to use SharePoint Calculated column to count percentage based on the column values and then you can use SharePoint Column.

By default SharePoint Calculated column will not allow more than 19 conditions in one IF function and there you can use concatenate function.

Reference -> [How to write multiple conditional formula (39 conditions) for 7 columns in Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302904/how-to-write-multiple-conditional-formula-39-conditions-for-7-columns-in-share/302914#302914)

Hope it will helpful to you.